# Spring error - springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found

Tags: java, spring, maven, weblogic

I'm trying to pass an object to another class using *Spring* (I'm not sure I'm using the right terms, I'm very new to *Spring*) this way:

```java
TestServicesUtils.getTemplate().postForLocation(
     "http://"
     + serverConfig
     + ":"
     + port
     + "/test/rest/TestResultService/insertTestResult/",
    results);
```

When I ran the program it gets to that line and it trows an `Exception`:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:76)
```

The class that's trying to connect to:

```java
@Service("TestRestImpl")
@Path("TestResultService")
@Produces("application/json")
public class TesttRestImpl implements TestResultRest 
{ 
    ...
    @POST
    @Override
    @Path("/insertTestResult")
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    public void insertTestResult(TestRestCollection list) {
        testresultservicedao.insertTestResult(list.getListOfResults());
    }
}
```

The path seems to be fine, I don't know why it can't find the method.  Do I need to register the path?

Comment: Could you show us your *web.xml* file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your path is not correct. If you have a correct path and still get an error then is a mapping error.
But in this situation you have 404 error which means that path doesn't exist.

Change your path to : `@Path("/test/rest/TestResultService/insertTestResult/")`

Then if you have an error again you have to register your path to mapping conf.

Comment: Little did I know that I needed to add the ref bean to the application-context.xml

Answer (score 0):

Above answer gave me a direction!
If you get this error while calling one microservice from another and you have implemented concept of `context path` for microservices.
Consider providing context path as well, as part of microservice endpoint while making call.